# MySQL query to get last record in each category

Tags: mysql

I got two tables: **articles** and **categories** (about 20 categories), and I want to get the lastest 10 articles, but no more than one from a category.

Table **Articles**

```
id | title | text
```

Table **Categories**

```
id | name
```

Table **ArticlesCategories** (relationsl table between Articles and Categories)

```
article | category
```

Im using the query below but the problem is that the 10 results are not all the latest articles.

```
SELECT id, title, categoryId, categoryName
FROM ( 
        SELECT a.id, a.title, ac.category AS categoryId, c.name AS categoryName
        FROM articles AS a 
            LEFT JOIN articles_categories AS ac ON ac.article = a.id 
            LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON c.id = ac.category 
        WHERE ac.priority = 1 
        ORDER BY a.id DESC ) AS tmp_table 
GROUP BY categoryId LIMIT 10
```

Comment: latest based on what,do you have a date field?

Comment: Using ID field of Articles.

Comment: `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10` after GROUP BY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `ORDER BY id DESC`  to your query

This is the way of getting the last 10 rows is to reverse the order and select the first ten rows:

```
SELECT id, title, categoryId, categoryName
FROM ( 
        SELECT a.id, a.title, ac.category AS categoryId, c.name AS categoryName
        FROM articles AS a 
            LEFT JOIN articles_categories AS ac ON ac.article = a.id 
            LEFT JOIN categories AS c ON c.id = ac.category 
        WHERE ac.priority = 1 
        ORDER BY a.id DESC ) AS tmp_table 
GROUP BY categoryId  ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10
```

Comment: I got confused or isnt GROUP supposed to be executed before ORDER? In this case there should be no difference made by the ORDER BY.

Comment: You need to ORDER GROUPED DATA ? isn't it ?

Comment: This makes use of MySQL `group by` extensions.  These are *explicitly* documented as not guaranteed to work in this case.  The values for the columns other than `categoryId` come from *indeterminate* rows.  Read about it here:  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-extensions.html.